# RayCastHit2D causing inconsistent collissions

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2.5D top-down game. I created a script for placing Objects on my Grid. But it's behaving really weirdly. It snaps to grid as it should, but if the grid I try to place the Object on is on top of, or to the left of, an object in the game, it triggers a collission (See GIF):

[image]

I am using `RayCastHit2D` to detect collissions, this is my Script:

```c#
    public GameObject finalObject;

private Vector2 mousePos;
private RaycastHit2D rayHitCollision;
private RaycastHit2D rayHitInteractive;
private Renderer rend;
private Color green;
private Color red;

public LayerMask collisionLayer;
public LayerMask interactiveLayer;

void Start()
{
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    red = Color.red;
    red.a = .5f;

    green = Color.green;
    green.a = .5f;

    rend.material.SetColor("_Color", green);
}

void Update()
{
    //get pos of mouse
    mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    //place object at rounded mouse pos (snapping)
    transform.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Round(mousePos.x), Mathf.Round(mousePos.y));

    if (GameManager.manager.mainState == GameManager.MainState.PLACEMENT)
    {
        //In order to collide with object, they must be on same layer, this includes tilemap stuff

        rayHitCollision = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, collisionLayer);

        //if tile is colliding with other tile show red, REMEMBER THIS IS EFFECTED BY LAYERS
        if (rayHitCollision.collider != null)
        {
            rend.material.SetColor("_Color", red);
        }
        //if not colliding, check for mouse press and place
        else
        {
            rend.material.SetColor("_Color", green);
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                if (rayHitCollision.collider == null)
                {
                    //place object
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to get my GameObjects to snap to the Grid I had to set the Pivots to bottom-right (If they are center, they get placed at Grid intersection). 
This means I had to customize their collider like so:

[image]

As you can see my Collider is exactly one grid (I use 16ppu):

[image]

I am stumped here, does anyone have any clue what is wrong here? Might be worth adding, I tried changing their colliders to size 0.9 instead of 1, but thats just disables `RaycastHit2D` completely, and I could place Objects on top of each other etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that due to your alignment fixes your raycast is firing from the tile corner instead of the centre, which produces ambiguous results. You could test this out by seeing if adding an offset of half a tile to the raycast start position fixes this (not sure whether + or -):

```
rayHitCollision = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, collisionLayer);
```

Feel free to downvote if this answer is incorrect. It is based on a hunch and I don't have unity on this machine to try it out.

Comment: Why would I downvote someone trying to help me :) This sounds like a good (ish) Idea and I will try it as soon as I get home!

Comment: Your hunch seems to be in the right way, I changed it to `rayHitCollision = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0), Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, collisionLayer);` and now the only grid triggering collision that shouldnt be is top-left. Just seems so odd that I would have to change pivots and things like this just to make it snap to grid. Why wouldnt pivot center snap to the grid... seems silly